# How to automate unpacked chrome extensions without crx file using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome-extension

I have been looking for options but they are limited to implementation of crx files only and we don't have that I have used these alternates which I have pasted below as well but they are not working :-

```
1. options = new ChromeOptions();
         options.AddArgument("--load-extension=" + unpackedExtensionPath);

2. options.add_argument("--load-extension=./Edit-This-Cookie")
    
    
3. options.addArguments("chrome.switches","--disable-extensions");
        options.addArguments("--load-extension" , 
   
    
4. options.addArguments("chrome.switches","--disable-extensions");
```

Comment: js != java. Are you sure it is Java?

Answer (score 0):

If you can only work with crx files, how about creating a crx file before your tests?

- Go to: chrome://extensions/
- Turn on developer mode (top right slider)
- Pack the extension.

First time you do it, you only need the unpacked folder path:

[image: extensions page in chrome]

[image]

After you've got your crx file, add it to your chrome options.

```
options.addExtensions(new File("/pathToExtension.crx"));
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion will try this